# how to reduce Geoserver WMTS rendering time?

Tags: raster, geoserver, gdal, wmts

I am publishing 100 Gb of aerial image til on GeoServer using pyramid technique. I have made GeoServer in a production environment according to GeoServer manual "Running in a production environment".
I have prepared data using gdal_retile:

`gdal_retile.py -s_srs EPSG:27700 -v -r bilinear -levels 4 -ps 500 500 -co 'TILED=YES' -co 'COMPRESS=JPEG'  -targetDir OUTPUT *.jpg`

Input jpg image details:

> Driver: JPEG/JPEG JFIF Files: SS0096.jpg
>          SS0096.jgw Size is 4000, 4000 Coordinate System is `' Origin = (200000.000000000000000,197000.000000000000000) Pixel Size =
>   (0.250000000000000,-0.250000000000000) Metadata:
>   EXIF_BitsPerSample=8 8 8   EXIF_ColorSpace=65535   EXIF_Compression=1 
>   EXIF_DateTime=2016:09:08 07:20:28   EXIF_Orientation=1
>   EXIF_PhotometricInterpretation=2   EXIF_PixelXDimension=4000
>   EXIF_PixelYDimension=4000   EXIF_PlanarConfiguration=1
>   EXIF_ResolutionUnit=2   EXIF_SamplesPerPixel=3   EXIF_Software=Adobe
>   Photoshop CS2 Windows   EXIF_XResolution=(72)   EXIF_YResolution=(72)
>   Image Structure Metadata:   COMPRESSION=JPEG   INTERLEAVE=PIXEL
>   SOURCE_COLOR_SPACE=YCbCr Corner Coordinates: Upper Left  ( 
>   200000.000,  197000.000) Lower Left  (  200000.000,  196000.000) Upper Right (  201000.000,  197000.000) Lower Right (  201000.000, 
>   196000.000) Center      (  200500.000,  196500.000) Band 1 Block=4000x1 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Red   Overviews: 2000x2000,
>   1000x1000, 500x500, 160x160   Image Structure Metadata:
>       COMPRESSION=JPEG Band 2 Block=4000x1 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Green   Overviews: 2000x2000, 1000x1000, 500x500, 160x160   Image Structure
>   Metadata:
>       COMPRESSION=JPEG Band 3 Block=4000x1 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Blue   Overviews: 2000x2000, 1000x1000, 500x500, 160x160   Image Structure
>   Metadata:
>       COMPRESSION=JPEG

Windows Server configuration is `Intel Xeon E5, 2.20GHz (2 processor) and 32gb RAM`. But when I am accessing this layer using WMTS service, it is taking a lot of time `(around 20-30 minutes)` to load completely.

Can anyone suggest me how to reduce rendering time?

Comment: Please clarify what you mean with "load completely". With what client, ar what resolution?

Comment: load completely in QGIS and ArcGIS at resolution 1:2000000.

Comment: how did you prepare your data files?

Comment: I have updated my question. please looks once.

Comment: For preparing the data, I followed following steps:
 
 1. optimize data with gdal_translate
 gdal_translate -co "TILED=YES" -co "BLOCKXSIZE=512" -co "BLOCKYSIZE=512" input.tif   output.tif
 

 2. added overviews with gdal_addo
 gdaladdo -r average output.tif 2 4 8 16 32
 

 3. Created the pyramid with GDAL retile 
 gdal_retile.py -s_srs EPSG:27700 -v -r bilinear -levels 4 -ps 500 500 -co "TILED=YES" -co 'COMPRESS=JPEG' -co "BLOCKXSIZE=256" -co "BLOCKySIZE=256" -ot Byte -useDirForEachRow -targetDir Output output.tif

Answer (score 3):

The best advice is to follow [Paul Ramsey's advice](http://blog.cleverelephant.ca/2015/02/geotiff-compression-for-dummies.html):

> So, to sum up, your best format for image serving is:
>
> - GeoTiff, so you can avoid proprietary image formats and nonsense, with
> - JPEG compression, for visually fine results with much space savings, and
>   YCBCR color, for even smaller size, and
> - internal tiling, for fast access of random squares of data, and
> - overviews, for fast access of zoomed out views of the data.

For `gdal_translate` he recommends the following options:

```
gdal_translate \
  -co COMPRESS=JPEG \
  -co PHOTOMETRIC=YCBCR \
  -co TILED=YES \
  5255C.tif 5255C_JPEG_YCBCR.tif
```

and for overviews:

```
gdaladdo \
  --config COMPRESS_OVERVIEW JPEG \
  --config PHOTOMETRIC_OVERVIEW YCBCR \
  --config INTERLEAVE_OVERVIEW PIXEL \
  -r average \
  5255C_JPEG_YCBCR.tif \
  2 4 8 16
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your valuable answer. I followed these steps and reprocess the data again. but when I am rendering it using WMTS in QGIS, still it is taking a lot of time. Please, can you let me know what I am doing wrong? and one more question is my server configuration sufficient for publishing 100-300 GB of raster data?