# GeoServer mosaic plugin slow at higher zoom level

Tags: raster, geoserver, wmts

I have published 71204 raster Geotif images on Geoserver Using Mosaic technique. When I am rendering it on QGIS using WMS tiled true. It's working well at the zome level 1:500 to 1:6000, after the zoom level 1:60000 rendering speed is slow and I am getting following error

> 2018-05-29 07:14:16,700 ERROR [geoserver.ows] - 
>   java.lang.IllegalStateException: No compression type set!     at
>   javax.imageio.ImageWriteParam.setCompressionQuality(Unknown Source)
>     at
>   org.geoserver.wms.legendgraphic.JAISupport.encode(JAISupport.java:176)
>     at
>   org.geoserver.wms.legendgraphic.JPEGLegendGraphicResponse.write(JPEGLegendGraphicResponse.java:46)
>     at org.geoserver.ows.Dispatcher.response(Dispatcher.java:1019)  at
>   org.geoserver.ows.Dispatcher.handleRequestInternal(Dispatcher.java:274)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.AbstractController.handleRequest(AbstractController.java:174)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.handle(SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.java:50)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:963)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:897)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:861)
>     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:635)     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
>     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>     at
>   org.geoserver.filters.ThreadLocalsCleanupFilter.doFilter(ThreadLocalsCleanupFilter.java:28)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>     at
>   org.geoserver.filters.SpringDelegatingFilter$Chain.doFilter(SpringDelegatingFilter.java:75)
>     at
>   org.geoserver.wms.animate.AnimatorFilter.doFilter(AnimatorFilter.java:71)
>     at
>   org.geoserver.filters.SpringDelegatingFilter$Chain.doFilter(SpringDelegatingFilter.java:71)
>     at
>   org.geoserver.monitor.MonitorFilter.doFilter(MonitorFilter.java:144)
>     at
>   org.geoserver.filters.SpringDelegatingFilter$Chain.doFilter(SpringDelegatingFilter.java:71)
>     at
>   org.geoserver.filters.SpringDelegatingFilter.doFilter(SpringDelegatingFilter.java:46)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>     at
>   org.geoserver.platform.AdvancedDispatchFilter.doFilter(AdvancedDispatchFilter.java:50)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:316)
>     at
>   org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:69)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:126)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:90)
>     at
>   org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:73)
>     at
>   org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:92)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
>     at
>   org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:69)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:114)
>     at
>   org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:73)
>     at
>   org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:92)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
>     at
>   org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerAnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(GeoServerAnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:54)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
>     at
>   org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:69)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilterInternal(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:213)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>     at
>   org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:73)
>     at
>   org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:92)
>     at
>   org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerBasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(GeoServerBasicAuthenticationFilter.java:84)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
>     at
>   org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:69)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:91)
>     at
>   org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerSecurityContextPersistenceFilter$1.doFilter(GeoServerSecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:53)
>     at
>   org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:73)
>     at
>   org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:92)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:213)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:176)
>     at
>   org.geoserver.security.GeoServerSecurityFilterChainProxy.doFilter(GeoServerSecurityFilterChainProxy.java:152)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:262)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>     at
>   org.geoserver.filters.LoggingFilter.doFilter(LoggingFilter.java:88)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>     at
>   org.geoserver.filters.XFrameOptionsFilter.doFilter(XFrameOptionsFilter.java:89)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>     at org.geoserver.filters.GZIPFilter.doFilter(GZIPFilter.java:42)    at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>     at
>   org.geoserver.filters.SessionDebugFilter.doFilter(SessionDebugFilter.java:48)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>     at
>   org.geoserver.filters.FlushSafeFilter.doFilter(FlushSafeFilter.java:44)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:197)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:496)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:650)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:803)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:790)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1459)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
>     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
>     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) 2018-05-29 07:21:25,555 WARN
>   [geotools.rendering] - Unable to create this mosaic
>   org.geotools.data.DataSourceException: Unable to create this mosaic
>     at
>   org.geotools.gce.imagemosaic.RasterLayerResponse.prepareResponse(RasterLayerResponse.java:738)
>     at
>   org.geotools.gce.imagemosaic.RasterLayerResponse.processRequest(RasterLayerResponse.java:605)
>     at
>   org.geotools.gce.imagemosaic.RasterLayerResponse.createResponse(RasterLayerResponse.java:574)
>     at
>   org.geotools.gce.imagemosaic.RasterManager.read(RasterManager.java:1249)
>     at
>   org.geotools.gce.imagemosaic.ImageMosaicReader.read(ImageMosaicReader.java:897)
>     at
>   org.geotools.gce.imagemosaic.ImageMosaicReader.read(ImageMosaicReader.java:875)
>     at
>   org.geoserver.catalog.SingleGridCoverage2DReader.read(SingleGridCoverage2DReader.java:151)
>     at
>   org.geoserver.catalog.CoverageDimensionCustomizerReader.read(CoverageDimensionCustomizerReader.java:232)
>     at
>   org.geoserver.catalog.CoverageDimensionCustomizerReader.read(CoverageDimensionCustomizerReader.java:222)
>     at
>   org.geotools.renderer.lite.gridcoverage2d.GridCoverageReaderHelper.readSingleCoverage(GridCoverageReaderHelper.java:549)
>     at
>   org.geotools.renderer.lite.gridcoverage2d.GridCoverageReaderHelper.readCoverageInEnvelope(GridCoverageReaderHelper.java:334)
>     at
>   org.geotools.renderer.lite.gridcoverage2d.GridCoverageReaderHelper.readCoverages(GridCoverageReaderHelper.java:220)
>     at
>   org.geotools.renderer.lite.gridcoverage2d.GridCoverageRenderer.renderImage(GridCoverageRenderer.java:845)
>     at
>   org.geotools.renderer.lite.gridcoverage2d.GridCoverageRenderer.paint(GridCoverageRenderer.java:1208)
>     at
>   org.geotools.renderer.lite.StreamingRenderer$RenderCoverageReaderRequest.execute(StreamingRenderer.java:3516)
>     at
>   org.geotools.renderer.lite.StreamingRenderer$PainterThread.run(StreamingRenderer.java:3612)
>     at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown
>   Source)   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)  at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)    at
>   java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) Caused by:
>   java.lang.RuntimeException:
>   java.nio.channels.ClosedByInterruptException  at
>   org.geotools.data.store.ContentFeatureCollection$WrappingFeatureIterator.hasNext(ContentFeatureCollection.java:146)
>     at
>   org.geotools.gce.imagemosaic.catalog.CachingDataStoreGranuleCatalog.getGranuleDescriptors(CachingDataStoreGranuleCatalog.java:158)
>     at
>   org.geotools.gce.imagemosaic.RasterManager.getGranuleDescriptors(RasterManager.java:1259)
>     at
>   org.geotools.gce.imagemosaic.RasterLayerResponse.prepareResponse(RasterLayerResponse.java:669)
>     ... 20 more Caused by: java.nio.channels.ClosedByInterruptException
>     at java.nio.channels.spi.AbstractInterruptibleChannel.end(Unknown
>   Source)   at sun.nio.ch.FileChannelImpl.position(Unknown Source)  at
>   org.geotools.data.shapefile.files.FileChannelDecorator.position(FileChannelDecorator.java:89)
>     at
>   org.geotools.data.shapefile.dbf.IndexedDbaseFileReader.goTo(IndexedDbaseFileReader.java:132)
>     at
>   org.geotools.data.shapefile.IndexedShapefileFeatureReader.hasNext(IndexedShapefileFeatureReader.java:92)
>     at
>   org.geotools.data.store.ContentFeatureCollection$WrappingFeatureIterator.hasNext(ContentFeatureCollection.java:143)
>     ... 23 more 2018-05-29 07:21:25,555 ERROR [geotools.rendering] -
>   Unable to create this mosaic org.geotools.data.DataSourceException:
>   Unable to create this mosaic  at
>   org.geotools.gce.imagemosaic.RasterLayerResponse.prepareResponse(RasterLayerResponse.java:738)
>     at
>   org.geotools.gce.imagemosaic.RasterLayerResponse.processRequest(RasterLayerResponse.java:605)
>     at
>   org.geotools.gce.imagemosaic.RasterLayerResponse.createResponse(RasterLayerResponse.java:574)
>     at
>   org.geotools.gce.imagemosaic.RasterManager.read(RasterManager.java:1249)
>     at
>   org.geotools.gce.imagemosaic.ImageMosaicReader.read(ImageMosaicReader.java:897)
>     at
>   org.geotools.gce.imagemosaic.ImageMosaicReader.read(ImageMosaicReader.java:875)
>     at
>   org.geoserver.catalog.SingleGridCoverage2DReader.read(SingleGridCoverage2DReader.java:151)
>     at
>   org.geoserver.catalog.CoverageDimensionCustomizerReader.read(CoverageDimensionCustomizerReader.java:232)
>     at
>   org.geoserver.catalog.CoverageDimensionCustomizerReader.read(CoverageDimensionCustomizerReader.java:222)
>     at
>   org.geotools.renderer.lite.gridcoverage2d.GridCoverageReaderHelper.readSingleCoverage(GridCoverageReaderHelper.java:549)
>     at
>   org.geotools.renderer.lite.gridcoverage2d.GridCoverageReaderHelper.readCoverageInEnvelope(GridCoverageReaderHelper.java:334)
>     at
>   org.geotools.renderer.lite.gridcoverage2d.GridCoverageReaderHelper.readCoverages(GridCoverageReaderHelper.java:220)
>     at
>   org.geotools.renderer.lite.gridcoverage2d.GridCoverageRenderer.renderImage(GridCoverageRenderer.java:845)
>     at
>   org.geotools.renderer.lite.gridcoverage2d.GridCoverageRenderer.paint(GridCoverageRenderer.java:1208)
>     at
>   org.geotools.renderer.lite.StreamingRenderer$RenderCoverageReaderRequest.execute(StreamingRenderer.java:3516)
>     at
>   org.geotools.renderer.lite.StreamingRenderer$PainterThread.run(StreamingRenderer.java:3612)
>     at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown
>   Source)   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)  at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)    at
>   java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) Caused by:
>   java.lang.RuntimeException:
>   java.nio.channels.ClosedByInterruptException  at
>   org.geotools.data.store.ContentFeatureCollection$WrappingFeatureIterator.hasNext(ContentFeatureCollection.java:146)
>     at
>   org.geotools.gce.imagemosaic.catalog.CachingDataStoreGranuleCatalog.getGranuleDescriptors(CachingDataStoreGranuleCatalog.java:158)
>     at
>   org.geotools.gce.imagemosaic.RasterManager.getGranuleDescriptors(RasterManager.java:1259)
>     at
>   org.geotools.gce.imagemosaic.RasterLayerResponse.prepareResponse(RasterLayerResponse.java:669)
>     ... 20 more Caused by: java.nio.channels.ClosedByInterruptException
>     at java.nio.channels.spi.AbstractInterruptibleChannel.end(Unknown
>   Source)   at sun.nio.ch.FileChannelImpl.position(Unknown Source)  at
>   org.geotools.data.shapefile.files.FileChannelDecorator.position(FileChannelDecorator.java:89)
>     at
>   org.geotools.data.shapefile.dbf.IndexedDbaseFileReader.goTo(IndexedDbaseFileReader.java:132)
>     at
>   org.geotools.data.shapefile.IndexedShapefileFeatureReader.hasNext(IndexedShapefileFeatureReader.java:92)
>     at
>   org.geotools.data.store.ContentFeatureCollection$WrappingFeatureIterator.hasNext(ContentFeatureCollection.java:143)
>     ... 23 more

I am using Geoserver 2.13.0 and Windows Server configuration is Intel Xeon E5, 2.20GHz (2 processor) and 64gb RAM.

Can anyone suggest me how to solve this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

71204 files is far too many to open at once, which is what you are asking GeoServer to do as you zoom out. Once the number of files goes above 1000 the recommendation is to switch to an [image pyramid store](http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/data/raster/imagepyramid.html).

I would group your tiffs into a VRT file using [`gdalbuildvrt`](http://www.gdal.org/gdalbuildvrt.html) and then follow [these instructions](http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/tutorials/imagepyramid/imagepyramid.html).

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. First of all, I tried image pyramid technique but I was getting the same problem. after the zoom level 1:60000 rendering speed is slow. Please look once [this question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/278583/how-to-reduce-geoserver-wmts-rendering-time)